# List connected storage devices in FreeBSD

Tags: freebsd, block-device

What's the FreeBSD variant of Linux's `lsblk` and `blkid`?

I want something that provides the same sort of information as `lsblk` does in the example below:

```
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
/dev/sda      8:0    0 465.8G  0 disk 
├─/dev/sda1   8:1    0  1007K  0 part 
├─/dev/sda2   8:2    0   256M  0 part /boot
├─/dev/sda3   8:3    0   9.8G  0 part [SWAP]
├─/dev/sda4   8:4    0  29.3G  0 part /
├─/dev/sda5   8:5    0  29.3G  0 part /var
├─/dev/sda6   8:6    0 297.6G  0 part /home
└─/dev/sda9   8:9    0  16.3G  0 part 
/dev/sr0     11:0    1  1024M  0 rom
```

I've tried running commands like `man -k blk` and `apropos dev`.  There's `devinfo`, but I'm not sure if that's what I'm really looking for since it doesn't seem to give me to `/dev/<DEVICE>` path for the devices listed.

I even tried `devstat`, but that seems equally unhelpful

EDIT:

All I *really* need to know is the `/dev/<DEVICE>` path for each ***block*** device connected, and maybe the label of said device (if any); regardless of whether or not they have been mounted yet.

Comment: I think I may have figured it out... I think `camcontrol devlist` is probably what I want.

Comment: `lsblk` is very essential and FreeBSD shold really consider adapting it.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

From what I can tell, `camcontrol devlist` is the closest thing to a `lsblk` variant for FreeBSD.  I'm not 100% sure that this is the best method, but its output is very close to what `lsblk` gives you, *if you only care about `/dev/<DEV-PATH>` and device names*:

```
$ camcontrol devlist
<VBOX HARDDISK 1.0>   at scbus0 target 0 lun 0 (ada0,pass0)
<VBOX CD-ROM 1.0>     at scbus1 target 0 lun 0 (pass1,cd0)
```

The position of the `/dev/DEV-PATH` in the output of `camcontrol devlist` seems to vary.  For example, on the FreeBSD wiki, the example `camcontrol devlist` output on one of the pages lists the `devpath` for the CD-ROM drive in the opposite order: `(cd0,pass0)` instead of `(pass1,cd0)`.

I'm not sure if or what the significance of this difference is.  So if you aren't familiar with `devpaths` in *BSD you may need to play around with it a bit in order to get it to work.

Answer (score 61):

Use `geom disk list`. This will show all disk-like devices (technically, every instance of GEOM "DISK" class).

For more information: [geom | FreeBSD Manual Pages](https://www.freebsd.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=geom)

Answer (score 10):

Adding to trasz' answer, `geom part list` shows the partitions in FreeBSD.  Similarly `geom md list` will get you the "memory disk" devices (similar to some uses of loop mounts in linux which are also listed by `lsblk(8)` - in other words block devices created by `mdconfig(8)` on FreeBSD and `losetup(8)` on linux).  See `geom(8)` for a list of classes (each of which can be listed if the geom class is loaded).

This is not quite the same experience that `lsblk(8)` and `blkid(8)` provide in linux, but provides much of the same information.  There's no direct linkage from `geom(4)` instances & providers to mountpoint currently in FreeBSD (cf., `mountpoint(1)` and `findmnt(8)` on linux).

Answer (score 4):

Give `pciconf` or `kldstat` a try.

Comment: no, I wasn't aware of either of them, but neither of them seem to be what I want.  This may just be a case of me being unfamiliar with the naming conventions used by *BSD for devices, but I doubt it.

Comment: Log files should also list detected devices, but not sure that will help you. What do you want to achieve ?

Comment: Use `pciconf -l` or `pciconf -lv`

Answer (score 4):

I think `gpart list` is the closest thing to `lsblk`. It will show you all devices and their partitions (and a lot of extra information as well).

Answer (score 3):

all of the FreeBSD tools are "unreadable", this script mimics lsblk well:
https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/lsblk-8-command-for-freebsd.56008/

```
wget https://forums.freebsd.org/attachments/lsblk-sh-txt.3085/
cp index.html /usr/local/bin/lsblk.sh
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/lsblk.sh
```

Comment: What do you mean "unreadable", in what way are they unreadable?

Comment: I notice that this post is essentially a link to a form post that contains an attachment. Could you instead post the contents of that script here, so that your answer is self-contained? Thank you.

Comment: lsblk has a readable form of displaying drive hierarchy, just look at the question. i understand people don't want to look at df / mount and other nauseating tool outputs, and so far this is the best option.

Comment: @user533385 I can't speak for other users, but I'd hardly call `df/mount`'s default output nauseating.  Perhaps it's harder to understand at a glance, but then again it's the sort of thing you should take the time to understand irrespective of format.

Comment: this lsblk script is now also available on [ports](https://www.freshports.org/sysutils/lsblk/) and can be installed via `pkg install lsblk`

Comment: great, finally a productive properly formatted drive list with hierarchy in freebsd. welcome to 90s ;)

Comment: @ArtiZirk 's comment is now worthy of being an answer in it's own right - FreeBSD users finally do have a `lsblk` - I wonder whether the author of that has considered a `blkid` equivalent as well? 8-)

Comment: Ah, `blkid` is also available now, it is installed as part of the `e2fsprogs` package - so do `pkg install e2fsprogs` to get it installed.